# Disable touches everywhere except inside of a button? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, skspritenode

When I die in my game, I want to ignore all touch events by the user EXCEPT if the user taps inside of or on the reset game button. Here is my code.

```
  for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if died == true{
            Ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            if resetGame.containsPoint(location){

                restartScene()
                runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Woosh.wav", waitForCompletion: false))

            }

            else  {


                self.userInteractionEnabled = false



            }
```

This is all inside of my touchesBegan. This was my attempt at ignoring the user's touch unless the location of the touch was within the size of button. How can I ignore a user's touches everywhere on the screen except the button? resetGame is an SKSpriteNode image.

Comment: What class are we in?

Comment: In our gameScene.swift, inside of the touchesBegan method.

Comment: And what is resetGame variable? Maybe just post code for the whole class?

Comment: Actually. I have a question. What is the problem with this code? Can you still click on other things, or what is this code doing exactly?

Comment: It ignores all touches on the screen. Even the touches within the button. resetGame is just an image that when pressed, restarts the scene.

Comment: Did my answer below work for ya, or you looking for something else?

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, what is it doing now? It shouldn't be disabling everything, now.

Comment: Right. It enables everything. I just want the button to be able to be pressed, but any other touch outside of button to be ignored.

Comment: so okay, let's go back to the question, what is resetGame? Or post more code so I can see what resetGame etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to your issue.

The first case I want to propose to you is based to gesture recognizer.
You can separate the button from the other touches events and switch on/off the touches event by a boolean var like this:

### Gesture recognizers:

In the global var declaration section of your class:

```
var tapGesture :UITapGestureRecognizer!
var enableTouches:Bool = true

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameClass.simpleTap(_:)))
        self.tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        myBtn.name = "myBtn"
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return self.enableTouches
}

func simpleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("simple tap")
        if sender.state == .Ended {
           var touchLocation: CGPoint = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
           touchLocation = self.convertPointFromView(touchLocation)
           let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
           // do your stuff
           if touchedNode.name == "myBtn" { 
              // button pressed, do your stuff
           }
        }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
       if died == true { 
            self.enableTouches = false // disable all touches but leave gestures enabled
            //do whatever you want when hero is died
       }
}
```

---

### Only a Boolean

The second solution I want to propose is simply to stopping touches flow by using a simple boolean (it's not very elegant but it works).
This method look when button is tapped and the update method check if your hero is dead so all touches will be disabled:

In the global var declaration section of your class:

```
var enableTouches:Bool = true

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            super.didMoveToView(view)
            myBtn.name = "myBtn"
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if (!enableTouches) {
            return
        }

        let touch = touches.first
        let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)
        // do your stuff
        if touchedNode.name == "myBtn" { 
           // button pressed, do your stuff
           if died == true { 
                self.enableTouches = false // disable all touches
                //do whatever you want when hero is died
           }
        }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if (!enableTouches) {
            return
        }

        let touch = touches.first
        let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)
        // do your stuff

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if (!enableTouches) {
            return
        }
}
```

The first case permit to you to have always the gesture enabled so you can do also other stuff with gestures when your hero will be died. The second case stop your touches when you press your button and do the "die flow". Choose which may be the most suitable for you.